# Rectify an Image with Matlab's "camerParams" (Computer Vision System Toolbox)

Tags: image, matlab, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst, distortion

I'm working on a PIV-Workflow and I'm currently pre-processing the images. I need to get rid of the perspective distortion in the images. I do have the "image processing toolbox" and the "camera calibrator". I already got rid of the lens distortion with "undistortImage();" and the cameraParams object, which is inferred through a chessboard pattern.

**First Question:** Is it possible to use the cameraParams object to distort the image perspectively, so that my chessboard is rectified in the image?

**Second Question:** Since I were not able to use the cameraParams object, I tried to use the transformation functions manually. I tried to use pairs of control-points (with cpselection tool, the original image and a generated chessboard-image) and the fitgeotrans(movingPoints, fixedPoints, 'projective'); function to get my tform-object. However I always get the error message:

```
Error using fitgeotrans>findProjectiveTransform (line 189)
At least 4 non-collinear points needed to infer projective transform.
Error in fitgeotrans (line 102)
        tform = findProjectiveTransform(movingPoints,fixedPoints);
```

I tried a lot of different pairs of control-points (4 pairs or more). But I'm still getting this error. I believe I must overlook something here.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Stephan

Comment: **first question**: The only, only only reason of getting cameraParams is to undistrot the image. Therefore its not only possible, but "mandatory". **Second**: well it seems that the poins you are giving are in a line, and they should be non-collinear!

Comment: Thanks.
1.:
Yes, this is what I thought, too. To get the lens distortion, Matlab must do some perspective corrections internally. However I can't find a way to apply that correction to the image. "undistortImage()" is just doing the lens correction.

2.: My points are aranged in a rectangle or a rhomb, so not actually in a line. So this error is confusing me a little...

Comment: Here you have the equations : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using one of the calibration images, then all the information you need is in the `cameraParams` object.

Let's say you are using calibration image 1, and let's call it `I`.
First, undistort the image:

```
I = undistortImage(I, cameraParams);
```

Get the extrinsics (rotation and translation) for your image:

```
R = cameraParams.RotationMatrices(:,:,1);
t = cameraParams.TranslationVectors(1, :);
```

Then combine rotation and translation into one matrix:

```
R(3, :) = t;
```

Now compute the homography between the checkerboard and the image plane:

```
H = R * cameraParams.IntrinsicMatrix;
```

Transform the image using the inverse of the homography:

```
J = imwarp(I, projective2d(inv(H)));
imshow(J);
```

You should see a "bird's eye" view of the checkerboard.  If you are not using one of the calibration images, then you can compute `R` and `t` using the `extrinsics` function.

Another way to do this is to use `detectCheckerboardPoints` and `generateCheckerboardPoints`, and then compute the homography using `fitgeotform`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tried it and it works like a charm. Thumbs up!